# rs report design parametrized query for MySQL

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, parameters, report

I have a Mysql DB report with visual studio report server and is displaying correctly in report server.

but i want to do a parametrized query and after reading and searching i know the obdc driver cant pass @ and i have to use '?' but after trying a lot i cant figured out how to implemented.

I have a @parameter which use a secodn dataset that query the db for usernames

i have my main dataset with the where (`user` = '?') and in the dataset parameter tab i try putting an expression with the select query for user and try use the actual parameter.

am a little lost here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

got it in my case..., use

> where (`usernames` = ?)

in the query and in the parameters tab of the dataset use Parameter1 as name and in value match it with the created parameter in Parameters

[image]